# Extremely slow AVD fully allocates resources

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm beginner on Android applications. I followed the steps in tutorial and prepared development environment on Vista (Eclipse Helios + Android SDK 12 + JDK6).

I created a minimal AVD with 32mb SD card and 128mb ram, enable snapshot.
and set current AVD in run configurations of application as automatically.

Emulator is extremely slow and CPU usage 100% shared by eclipse and emulator, 
memory consume is also in limit.

Do you have any suggestion to optimize it? It's my first step in development android app, and i don't want to be discouraged.

Thanks a lot,
Semanur

Comment: The emulator can be a resource hog.  It is much smoother if you run it on an actual Android device.

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bluestacks App player or Youwave For Android.
Those emulators are very much faster than eclipse emulators. You will find that they are most likely runnning your app on a real phone.

Answer (score 0):

Emulators use significant resources but with a medium computer it should run ok.
Try creating a new emulator instance with default settings, HVGA and no snapshot and no sd card.
Use android 2.2 for this test.

This one should run pretty smoothly on a medium computer.

Let us know the results.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has stated, the emulator is terrible for testing. I'd suggest debugging on a device, even if that means only being able to test one API and screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Launching from a snapshot is also a way of cutting the loading time and resource load on the CPU. I found it to still take a considerate amount of time still, but it is less than half of what it took before.

Answer (score 0):

you can download and install genymotion virtual device,, it is 3x faster then normal AVD